# Is this a Beneficial JavaScript Refactoring for Summarizing an Array of Objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, refactoring, javascript-objects

This may not be typical of questions here, but I don't really have anyone I know to check this. I'm doing some refactoring of someone else's code, and just want a second opinion, because of course I *think* my work makes it better, but some validation from you pros out there would be helpful.

**Starting with an array like this:**

```
errorLog: [{
 errorCode: 11,
 errorDescription: "abc",
 date: "2017-01-01",
 severity: "H"
},{
 errorCode: 11,
 errorDescription: "abcd",
 date: "2017-01-02",
 severity: "H"
},{
 errorCode: 99,
 errorDescription: "abcd",
 date: "2017-01-02",
 severity: "H"
}]
```

**and trying to get results like this**:

```
errorSummary: [{
 errorCode: 11,
 severity: "H",
 count: 2
},{
 errorCode: 99,
 severity: "H",
 count: 1
}]
```

**this is the existing code**:

```
//instead of this, which is hard to reason about and debug (and includes a line that will never rturn true: if (hardErrorsSorted.includes...)):
let hardErrors = testData.filter(ts1 => ts1.severity === 'H');
let hardErrorsSorted = hardErrors.sort(this.mySorter);
for (let i = 0; i < hardErrorsSorted.length; i++) {
  if (i != hardErrorsSorted.length - 1) {
    if (hardErrorsSorted[i].errorCode != hardErrorsSorted[i + 1].errorCode) {
      let errorCount = this.getCount(hardErrorsSorted, hardErrorsSorted[i].errorCode);
      this.errorDataList.push({
        errorCode: hardErrorsSorted[i].errorCode,
        errorCodeType: 'H',
        errorCodeTotalCount: errorCount
      });
    }
  } else {
    if (hardErrorsSorted.includes(hardErrorsSorted[i].errorCode, 0)) {
    } else {
      let errorCount = this.getCount(hardErrorsSorted, hardErrorsSorted[i].errorCode);
      this.errorDataList.push({
        errorCode: hardErrorsSorted[i].errorCode,
        errorCodeType: 'H',
        errorCodeTotalCount: errorCount
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**and my refactoring:**

```
//use something like this, which is much easier to grasp at a glance, doesn't jump around, and is DRYer
let hardErrorCodes = testData.filter(ts => ts.severity === 'H').map(v => v.errorCode);
let hardErrorCounts = {};

//sum up the unique errors
for (let error of hardErrorCodes) {
  if (!(error in hardErrorCounts)) {
    hardErrorCounts[error] = 0;
  }
  hardErrorCounts[error]++;
}

//add the summed error counts to the master list
for (let error in hardErrorCounts) {
  this.errorDataList.push({
    errorCode: error, 
    errorCodeType: "H", 
    errorCodeTotalCount: hardErrorCounts[error]
  });
```

What do you all think? A helpful refactor? Or a waste of time?

Comment: [codereview.se]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that existed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could even go further:

```
const result = [], ids = {};

for(const {errorCode, severity} of hardErrorCodes){
  if(severity !== "H") continue;
  if(ids[errorCode]){
    ids[errorCode].count++;
  }else{
    result.push( ids[errorCode] = { severity, errorCode, count: 1});
  }
}
```

This makes it 3 times faster (in theory)

If you don't want to filter the severity:

```
for(const {errorCode, severity} of hardErrorCodes){
  if(ids[severity + errorCode]){
    ids[severity + errorCode].count++;
  }else{
    result.push( ids[severity + errorCode] = { severity, errorCode, count: 1});
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I've never seen an assignment in `push()` though; I don't quite understand what's happening there.

Comment: Oh, it must be because the object in `ids` for that error code points to the same structure as `result[index]`, right? I forget occasionally that objects are passed by reference and not value.

So my follow-up questions is, since I actually have 2 severities, how do I summarize each individually? Amend with `if(ids[errorCode] && ids[errorCode].severity === severity)`?

Comment: @redOctober13 yes, your first point is right. However, to merge by severity you need to do either `ids[severity][errorCode]` ( with some more logic) or maybe more easy: `ids[severity+errorCode]`

Comment: I'm not sure I do. This (https://jsfiddle.net/Las1qzeq/) seems to return the right answer. Do you see a bug in there?

Comment: @redOctober13 it does: http://jsbin.com/lukexireho/edit?console ( it does not join 11/W)

Comment: jsbin gets blocked here, but in my fiddle, it works fine. I want 11/H and 11/W to have their own counts, and in my fiddle, the result has 2 of each, which is right.

Comment: @redOctober13 add another `{
 errorCode: 11,
 errorDescription: "abcd",
 date: "2017-01-02",
 severity: "W"
},` and it will fail

Comment: If I add that, my results array contains `{severity: "W", errorCode: 11, count: 3}` which is exactly what I want. Are you seeing a different result?

Comment: @redOctober13 i bet you have a different order. Add another "H" and it will fail.

Comment: Added `let uniqueId = errorCode+severity` as you suggested, and then it works. Much thanks!

Comment: @redOctober13 glad to help ;)